# Tensorflow error in triplet_semihard_loss(): "ValueError: Dimensions must be equal"

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm using the `triplet_semihard_loss()` function from Tensorflow Addons in order to calculate triplet loss on feature embeddings.

The output of my ResNet-50, `embedding_output`, is `(None,8,8,2048)`.

The shape of my sparse ground truth labels, `y`, is `(None)`, i.e. the size of a batch, making it the expected 1D vector of integer IDs.

In my custom `train_step()` function I call `triplet_semihard_loss` and at this point in the code execution the following error shows:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 2048 and 8 for '{{node
 MatMul}} = BatchMatMulV2[T=DT_FLOAT, adj_x=false, adj_y=false](feature,
 transpose_1)' with input shapes: [?,8,8,2048], [2048,8,8,?].
```

The full error and my code can be seen [here](https://vehiclereidjupyternotebook.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/Full_pipeline-3.html).

**What is causing these dimensions to flip around?**

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I am having a similar problem

Answer (score 1):

I hope you already solved this issue.
If you haven't solved it yet, I reccomand you to add a Flatten Layer at the output of VGG16. Here's an example:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np

model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 244, 3))
flatten = layers.Flatten()(model.output)
dense = layers.Dense(256, activation=None)(flatten)
normalization = layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x, axis=1))(dense)
embedding = Model(model.input, normalization, name="Embedding")
```

I hope this will be useful.
Regards,

Andrea